# Trying to sort a list very specifically in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list, that in itself contains 52 individual lists. And inside these lists are one letter and one number. I need to sort this list numerically so that the list with the biggest number is at the beginning of the list, and so on.

Comment: There are numerous `sort(key=...)` answers here on stack overflow. Without more specific details we cannot help you, but I suspect that whatever your structure this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Is the number the first or second element of the inner list?

Comment: This sort of thing is bread and butter computer science. You should read about the topic generally, so that you can solve this stuff yourself. Likewise, familiarise yourself with the Python documentation.

Comment: Most of all, the various techniques are already covered [on the Python Wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting). Read up there first, then if you still have problems, post a more concrete question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the integer is the second element in the inner list:

```
sorted(your_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

This will return a sorted version of your original list, if you want to do it in place you can use the following:

```
your_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Note that instead of passing `reverse=True`, you could juse use `lambda x: -x[1]`, but personally I think using the `reverse` argument is a little more clear.

You can also use [`key=operator.itemgetter(1)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) if you prefer not to use `lambda`.

Comment: Possibly `key = lambda x: (x[1],x[0])` depending on what OP wants to have happen in the case where two lists have the same number.